# How do I change this code so it goes from white>green>black?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I have this chunk of code that produces a clickable box that changes colors from black --> green --> white by cycling through the shades of green whenever the mouse is clicked. I need the same thing to happen, except instead of getting gradually lighter, the box starts at white and gradually becomes darker.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.addEventListener('click', () => {
  div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color) + 5;
  var c = Math.min(div.dataset.color % 512, 255);
  var c2 = Math.max((div.dataset.color % 512) - 255, 0);
  div.style.background = 'rgb(' + c2 + ',' + c + ',' + c2 + ')';
})
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: i suggest dont mix pure js with jquery

Comment: @guardio That isn’t jQuery…

Comment: @guradio there's no problem in doing that.

Answer (score 1):

By taking your code as a base, you simply have to invert `c` and `c2`, and then substract their result from `255` to get the reverse :

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color) + 5;
  // invert c and c2
  // c is the green channel
  // c2 the red and blue ones
  var c2 = Math.min(div.dataset.color % 512, 255);
  var c = Math.max((div.dataset.color % 512) - 255, 0);
  // substract the values from 255 to get white to black instead of b2w
  div.style.background = 'rgb(' + (225 - c2) + ',' + (255 - c) + ',' + (255 - c2) + ')';
})
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Once the operations are cleaned it gives :

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 510;
div.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  // we substract 5 at each iteration
  div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color) - 5;
  if(div.dataset.color < 0) // negative modulo
    div.dataset.color = 510;

  var c = Math.min(div.dataset.color, 255); // green channel
  var c2 = Math.max(div.dataset.color - 255, 0); // red and blue
  div.style.background = 'rgb(' + c2 + ',' + c + ',' + c2 + ')';
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

And the original black to white :

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // we add 5 at each iteration
  div.dataset.color = (parseInt(div.dataset.color) + 5) % 511;
  // This doesn't move
  var c = Math.min(div.dataset.color, 255); // green channel
  var c2 = Math.max(div.dataset.color - 255, 0); // red and blue
  div.style.background = 'rgb(' + c2 + ',' + c + ',' + c2 + ')';
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

And both directions :

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.dataset.inc = 5; // add an increment value which will tell us the current direction
var f = e => { // moved to an rAF loop to avoid killing our mice
  div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color) + (+div.dataset.inc);
  if(div.dataset.color < 0 || div.dataset.color > 512){
    // change the direction
    div.dataset.inc = div.dataset.inc * -1;
    }
  
  // This doesn't move
  var c = Math.min(div.dataset.color, 255); // green channel
  var c2 = Math.max(div.dataset.color - 255, 0); // red and blue
  div.style.background = 'rgb(' + c2 + ',' + c + ',' + c2 + ')';
requestAnimationFrame(f);
};
f();
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014488/how-do-i-change-this-code-so-it-goes-from-whitegreenblack/44014647?noredirect=1#comment75083460_44014647

Comment: @guest271314 does it mean continuously ? (black to green to white to green to black ...)?

Comment: White to green to black, black to green to white, repeat. Though that requirement is at linked comment, not at original Question. OP accepted this users' Answer yesterday, unaccepted today, leaving the linked comment without updating actual Question. Decided to update Answer for the code itself, in spite of OP's omission as to, apparently, updated requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are!

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<style>
  #myDiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000000;
  }

</style>

<script>
  var $div = document.querySelector('div');
  var index = 1;

  $div.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var color;

    if (index === 1) {
      color = 'white';
      index++
    } else if (index === 2) {
      color = 'green';
      index++
    } else if (index === 3) {
      color = 'black';
      index = 1;
    }

    $div.style.background = color

  })
</script>
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but instead of only including white, green, and black, I need it to cycle through the entire spectrum of greens per click. So the box starts as white, then when I click it, it becomes slightly greener, and with every click it continues in this fashion until the box is dark.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the procedure at Question, begin at with an array with values set to `[255, 255, 255]`, decrement value at indexes `0` and `2` by `5` at each click event until `0` is reached for value at each index `0` and `2`, then decrement value at index `1` by `5` until `0` is reached.

When `0` is reached for `r`, `g`, `b`, increment `g` to `255`, then increment `r` and `b` to `255`, repeat.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
div.dataset.color = "[255, 255, 255]";
div.dataset.from = true;
const fromWhiteToGreenToBlackAndBack = () => {
  let [r, g, b] = JSON.parse(div.dataset.color);
  if (JSON.parse(div.dataset.from)) {
    if (g !== 0) {
      if (r > 0) {
        r = b -= 5;
      } else {
        g -= 5;
      }
    } else {
      div.dataset.from = false;
    }
  } else {
    if (g < 255) {
      g += 5;
    } else {
      r = b += 5;
    }
    if (r === 255) {
      div.dataset.from = true;
    }
  }
  div.dataset.color = JSON.stringify([r, g, b]);
  div.style.background = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
}
div.addEventListener("click", fromWhiteToGreenToBlackAndBack);
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: 1s background ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but I don't want a border on the box and I want the color inside that changes to only be the spectrum of greens. So I want it to start at white, then gradually become pure green, and then gradually become black. Each click should change the color, but the colors that it cycles between should only be in the green family

Comment: On the right track! I need to box to start as white and then become incrementally greener with each click, not just go from white to pure green. So, I would need it to include the tints like #19ff19, #32ff32, #4cff4c, #66ff66, etc.

Comment: I just realized, I need the color to loop back to white after it's been clicked all the way to pure black so It can be clicked continuously and it cycles through for as long as it remains to be clicked.

Comment: @Rekigama _"I just realized, I need the color to loop back to white after it's been clicked all the way to pure black so It can be clicked continuously and it cycles through for as long as it remains to be clicked."_ How is that requirement related to original Question?

Answer (score 0):

If [you can use `hsl()`](https://caniuse.com/#search=hsl), the third value goes from 0 (black) to 50% (green in this case) to 100% (white)

```js
const div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 100;
div.addEventListener('click', () => {
  div.dataset.color = Math.max(0, parseInt(div.dataset.color, 10) - 5);
  div.style.background = 'hsl(115, 100%, '+div.dataset.color+'%)';
})
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```